# Creating REST Api in MVC 5 with Byte[] as Parameter

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

I need to create a REST Api in MVC 5 with few parameters like:

```
SaveNoteBook(int UserID, int InstituteClassId, int NoteBookSubject, int NoteBookPageId, byte[] NoteBookData)
```

1. How do I create a REST api with MVC 5 and can be consumed with any
   platform like android, ios, windows?
2. How to consume this api in c#?

Thanks

Comment: *I need to create a REST Api in MVC 5 with few parameters like* and what is stopping you?(where is the problem?)

Comment: i have created the api like this but dont know how to consume this in c# and android

Comment: so what's your problem? do you want to create one with byte[] parameter or you want to consume the one you've already created, in C#?

Comment: yes i want to create one and consume with c# also

Answer (score 0):

1. REST means your methods would be closer to what HTTP verbs are.
2. For byte[] NoteBookData parameter, you can tweak it as base64 string so as to get consumed by any of the platform.